# Add additional dependency in maven-war-plugin

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

In our web project there are a couple of executions of maven-war-plugin that generates war files for each environment. I need to add a new dependency to one of them. So far we have been doing this using overlays but this approach does not operate on drpendencies and as a result we often end up with the same library added twice in different versions. 
Is there any way to create multiple wars per one build(not multiple builds with different profiles) with custom dependencies?

Comment: First creating war files by execution of maven-war-plugin multiple times is not the best...i assume your different wars differ only in `configuration files` than you need. If you need different dependencies you should create separate projects for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hy Tomasz W

I have created a sample pom.xml file

With the maven-war-plugin alone you cannot add a dependency for only one execution. but in my working example i separated the war plugin output into separate folders and then with the dependency plugin i copied the depencencies required only for "dev" war into the specific WEB-INF/lib folder...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.stefanheimberg.stackoverflow-34083152</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow-34083152</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- maven default properties -->
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
        <maven.compiler.showWarnings>true</maven.compiler.showWarnings>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-dev-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeGroupIds>org.eclipse.persistence</excludeGroupIds>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>eclipselink</excludeArtifactIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-dev/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeGroupIds>org.hibernate</excludeGroupIds>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>hibernate-core</excludeArtifactIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-test/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-dev-package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <warName>${project.build.finalName}-dev</warName>
                            <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-dev</webappDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-test-package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <warName>${project.build.finalName}-test</warName>
                            <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-test</webappDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

file output:

```
$ ls -l target/*/WEB-INF/lib/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  434678 Okt  1 15:03 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  445288 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  434678 Okt  1 15:03 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  313898 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089   75288 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089 5570751 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-5.0.5.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  113371 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  187752 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  714194 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089   85147 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089   66802 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089   63777 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  109318 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-dev/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  445288 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089   21007 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  434678 Okt  1 15:03 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  313898 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089 9051263 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/eclipselink-2.6.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  187752 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  714194 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089   85147 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  162126 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089   66802 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089   63777 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 heimbergs 1049089  109318 Dez  4 13:49 target/stackoverflow-34083152-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
```

you see the dev war contains the hibernate jars incl transitive dependencies and the test war contains the eclipselink jar incl. transitive dependencies.

i think this is not a good usage of maven. but it should work. and it is not scaleable.. and you must then manage all of the exclude lists for all different war files... the pom.xml could be really fast a mess...

**recommendation**:
perhaps it would be a good idea, to take a closer look at the architecture of the application. a deployment unit should be the same for all environments.

**UPDATE**

- updated the example with transitive depencencies...

Comment: This approach is very similar to the overlay I mentioned and causes the same problem - it does not care about duplicated libraries. Moreover dependency:copy copies the jar without dependencies.

Comment: ok,. i have updated the answer. i think it is a little hack. but a working solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. Unfortunately it seems that exclusions in maven-dependency-plugin don't exclude transitive dependencies. In your example antlr is required only by hibernate but it is in the package with eclipselink as well. I agree that this is not the best structure but due to the build & deployment process in my company it cannot be easily changed.

Comment: ok i see.... even with <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive> it is not the expected result... i think my example is the "most" you get from maven for your problem/constellation